# Open multiple terminals in a for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Recently I changed to `lxde` on Ubuntu. And after switching it changed my `x-terminal-emulator` to `lxterm`.

My script was doing the following:

Go through a for loop and open a new terminal window and then run a script in that terminal. It would open multiple terminals at the same time running that script in all the different windows.

After switching to `lxde` it will loop through and wait for each terminal window to finish the script before the next terminal window launches. I want it to do what it was doing.

I fixed this issue by changing my `x-terminal-emulator` back to the `gnome-terminal`. Now it works fine. However, this is a script system that a few people use and they are all using different environments and terminal emulators. How can I make sure this works for all the different terminal emulators or at least for `xterm` or whatever the one everyone would have.

---

Code snippet:

```
for blah in something
do
    x-terminal-emulator -e bash my_script.sh
done
```

Comment: See this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91642/22222).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do

```
for blah in something
do
    x-terminal-emulator -e bash my_script.sh &
done
```

the ampersand (`&`) at the end makes the command run "in background". that means the next command (the next loop iteration) can start executing immediately without waiting for the first to finish.

beware that this might crash the system if `something` is large. because a bunch of terminals will try to run `my_script.sh` all at once.

if you want to keep the terminal open to read the output see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512055/avoid-gnome-terminal-close-after-script-execution/3531426#3531426

Comment: is there any way to prevent the newly-spawned child terminals from exiting? I'm doing this specifically so I can see all of their output, but they disappear immediately after running the script, so I can't see their output :(

Comment: Update: I was able to get this working with `x-terminal-emulator -e bash -i my_script.sh &` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709267